# Long Polling in win. store apps

Tags: c#, wpf, json, windows-store-apps

How can i imlement `Long Polling` in c# code. I don't found anything in Google. Maybe there is a sample code?

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
while(true)
{
 //CHECK IF WORK DONE AND NEED TO BREAK
 //YES ?
 break;
 //NO ?
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

this is how long polling implemented. but its bad to block a thread when we consider huge traffic and long running tasks.

Comment: can u please tell me what you are trying to achieve so that we can help you better

Comment: There is the server, from this server comes notifications, i want to catch this notifications

Comment: Read about SignalR. Its very easy to use and yet efficient